# when i run `ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from= to solve the problem it gives me this error "Could not find package.json"

Tags: angularjs

when i run `ng serve` on node js command prompt i got this error "The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found". and after i run this command to`ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=11.2.10` got also this error An unhandled exception occurred: Could not find package.json
See "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-Lbnxei\angular-errors.log" for further details.

can any one help me

Answer (score 11):

Try like this

```
ng update @angular/cli --from 10 --to 11 --migrate-only
```

This is wrong syntax `--from=11.2.10`